# How to get reference for TextView which is not in activity_main.xml?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, textview

wordonlist.xml:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHiragana"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Hiragana"
        android:textColor="@color/blackColor"
        android:textColorHint="@color/blackColor"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
```

MainActivity:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tvHiragana = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHiragana);
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/JapaneseLetter.ttf");
    tvHiragana.setTypeface(tf,Typeface.BOLD);
```

Result:

> NullPointerException in the line tvHiragana.setTypeface(tf,Typeface.BOLD);

I think it is because of TextView which is not in activity_main.xml. How to get reference for TextView which is in wordonlist.xml?

Comment: where and how you display **wordonlist.xml** in **MainActivity** ??

Comment: you need to set the content of  `wordonlist.xml` to the activity and then initialize the textview and use the same. what you  are doing is wrong. you can `findViewById` of the current view hierarchy set to the activity

Comment: How can you set the typeface of another xml which is not in the view from this activity where you are loading activty_main.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
LayoutInflater ltInflater = getLayoutInflater();
View view = ltInflater.inflate(R.layout.text, null, false);
```

Comment: How to use 'view' in order get referenced?

Comment: `tvHiragana = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvHiragana);`

Answer (score 1):

Add below code

LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)   getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       View customView= (View) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.wordonlist, null);

```
            TextView tvHiragana = (TextView) customView findViewById(R.id.tvHiragana);
              Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/JapaneseLetter.ttf");
              tvHiragana.setTypeface(tf,Typeface.BOLD);
```

Let me know if you still face problem

Comment: underlining customView in the line:TextView tvHiragana = (TextView) customView findViewById(R.id.tvHiragana);

Comment: i missed the the dot, it was a typo try now  TextView tvHiragana = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.tvHiragana);
              Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/JapaneseLetter.ttf");
              tvHiragana.setTypeface(tf,Typeface.BOLD);

Comment: Thanks a bunch, it got referenced. If let me, can I ask one more question from you? Using code above I could not change font-family(typeface) for text view. What do you think, what can be a problem? Eclipse is not giving any error.

Comment: where are you creating font folder

Comment: I am creating fonts folder inside Assets

Comment: try once removing the Typeface.BOLD and check other part works, because the code looks good

Comment: removed Typeface.BOLD. It is not changing. What else can be problem?

Comment: Maybe because textview inside listview

Comment: try changing the font to some other font, other than JapaneseLetter, may be some problem with this particular font.

Comment: I tried it for more than 15 fonts...Anyways thank you for your help and patience. I appreciate your help. TNX

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Layout inflator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) to load an xml file which is not in the activity layout

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService
      (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)
```

Comment: What should be done after inflating? I have added your code before TextView reference. Replaced context to this. Now it is giving same error:nullpointer exception

Answer (score 0):

You should use Infalter to add any layout that is not in main.xml

```
LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       View textview= (View) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.wordonlist, null);

                TextView tvHiragana = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHiragana);
                  Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/JapaneseLetter.ttf");
                  tvHiragana.setTypeface(tf,Typeface.BOLD);
```

Comment: 08-22 12:25:38.195: E/AndroidRuntime(323): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.joericharduz.akita/com.joericharduz.akita.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout